# Can one apply a WKB method to an inhomogeneous first order differential equation in order to find the asymptotic expansion of the solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, approximation

Consider
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon \frac{dy}{dx} = Q(x)y + R(x)
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon$ is a small parameter.  Can one apply a WKB method to find an asymptotic expansion for the solution?

I expect to obtain
\begin{equation}
y(x) \sim - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{Q(x)} \frac{d}{dx}\right)^n \frac{R(x)}{Q(x)}
\end{equation}
(I am aware that this is a divergent sum), but I have been unsuccessful in recovering this form by using WKB methods.

Comment: Does the explicit solution to your problem by an integrating factor not suit your needs?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I'm afraid not. I've also tried to find an asymptotic expansion of the explicit solution, but without success.

Comment: If you have a particular $Q$ and $R$ you're interested in I could give it a go and see if it goes anywhere, if you'd like.

Comment: One example is $Q(x) = e^{i x}$ and $R(x) = 1$.  Then the given series is the asymptotic expansion of the exponential integral, and the explicit solution also yields the exponential integral.  I'm fairly confident that the given series is correct to some approximation, and I'd like to use it for numerics.  But being fairly confident is not enough for implementation.  Perhaps one can find an asymptotic expansion of the explicit solution?

Comment: One can show that an infinite number of integration by parts yields the sum I have written.  Does that count as a valid asymptotic expansion?

Comment: It's an asymptotic expansion only if you can show that the remainder term is smaller asymptotically than the previous term.  I think for some functions that is the asymptotic, but for others it isn't.  I had real-valued functions in mind when I was thinking about it before, and I think I can give an example where the asymptotic is different from the given series.  I'll work it out and post a CW answer later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the differential equation is solved by

$$
y(x) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_0^x Q(\xi)\,d\xi\right)\left[y(0) + \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^x \exp\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_0^\zeta Q(\xi)\,d\xi\right) R(\zeta)\,d\zeta \right]. \tag{1}
$$

Unless we require $y(0) = 0$ then we will always have a term of the form $y(0)\exp\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_0^x Q(\xi)\,d\xi\right)$, and if the integral here is positive for some $x$ then this will not behave like the asymptotic series you propose as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

The integral in the other term is of Laplace-type, and the largest/smallest contributions of its integrand come from neighborhoods of the roots of $Q(\zeta) = 0$ (assuming there are any).

Let's investigate the example $Q(x) = 2x$, $R(x) = 1$.  In this case $(1)$ becomes

$$
y(x) = e^{x^2/\epsilon} \left[y(0) + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right)\right].
$$

Assuming $x > 0$ we have

$$
\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\right) = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\pi}} \frac{e^{-x^2/\epsilon}}{x} + \frac{\epsilon^{3/2}}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{e^{-x^2/\epsilon}}{x^3} + O\left(\epsilon^{5/2} e^{-x^2/\epsilon}\right)
$$

as $\epsilon \to 0^+$, so

$$
y(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\epsilon}} e^{x^2/\epsilon} + y(0) e^{x^2/\epsilon} - \frac{1}{2x} + \frac{\epsilon}{4x^3} + O(\epsilon^2).
$$

Notice that your expansion doesn't pick up either of the exponentially diverging terms but does agree with the part $1/2x + \epsilon/4x^3 + \cdots$.  If you know you can ignore any diverging terms for your application then it looks like your series is the way to go.  Otherwise it doesn't give you enough information.

---

As an example of how one might obtain the asymptotic behavior of the exponential terms  we'll again take $Q(x) = 2x$ but this time let $R(x)$ be an arbitrary function which is analytic at $x = 0$.  Then $(1)$ becomes

$$
y(x) = e^{x^2/\epsilon}\left(y(0) + \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^x e^{-\zeta^2/\epsilon} R(\zeta)\,d\zeta \right). \tag{2}
$$

Assuming $x > 0$ is fixed we can appeal to Watson's lemma and obtain an asymptotic expansion for the integral here by expanding $R(\zeta)$ in Taylor series around $\zeta = 0$.  Using the fact that

$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-\zeta^2/\epsilon} \zeta^k\,d\zeta = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right) \epsilon^{(k+1)/2}
$$

we get

$$
y(x) \approx e^{x^2/\epsilon}\left(y(0) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{R^{(k)}(0) \Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{k!} \epsilon^{(k-1)/2}\right)
$$

as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: Brilliant!  This has been of considerable help.  But allow me to ask some further questions.  Firstly, what is the definition of a Laplace-type integral?  Secondly, let's suppose that for the domain of $x$ I'm interested in $\Re Q(x) \leq 0$.  Then I would expect that the solution to the homogeneous equation drops out of the asymptotic expansion, as do the extra exponentially diverging terms.  It seems that the extra terms other than the series I expected are due to the Stokes phenomenon of asymptotics for crossing over to $\Re Q(x) > 0$—is this correct?

Comment: Thirdly, are the exponentially diverging terms always a complementary solution?  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: By "Laplace-type integral" I mean an integral of the form $$\int_a^b e^{ng(x)}f(x)\,dx.$$ Asymptotic analysis of these integrals can often be performed by the Laplace method or the saddle point method.  If you always have $\operatorname{Re} Q(x) \leq 0$ **and** $x \geq 0$ then the solution to the homogeneous equation, $y(0)\exp\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_0^x Q(\xi)\,d\xi\right)$, will indeed be exponentially small compared to the particular solution.  I'm not completely sure there won't be any exponentially diverging terms in the particular solution though.

Comment: I've added another answer to address your question about what can happen when $\operatorname{Re} Q(x) < 0$.  What do you mean by a complementary solution?

Comment: By `complementary solution' I meant the solution to the homogeneous equation.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> This answer is to address a question in the comments of the other answer on whether the exponentially diverging terms drop out in regions where $\operatorname{Re} Q(x) < 0$.

We'll study the particular case of $Q(x) = -\sin x$ and $R(x) = 1$ over the interval $2\pi < x < 3\pi$.  Note that we have $Q(x) < 0$ for all $x$ in question.

The general solution in $(1)$ becomes

$$
y(x) = y(0) e^{(\cos x - 1)/\epsilon} + \epsilon^{-1} e^{(\cos x - 1)/\epsilon} \int_0^x e^{(1-\cos \zeta)/\epsilon}\,d\zeta.
\tag{2}
$$

Let $\lambda = 1/\epsilon$, so that the integral in $(2)$ is

$$
I(x,\lambda) = \int_0^x e^{\lambda(1-\cos\zeta)}\,d\zeta.
$$

We will obtain the asymptotic behavior of this integral as $\lambda \to \infty$ using the Laplace method.

When $2\pi < x < 3\pi$, the maximum value of $1-\cos\zeta$ on the interval $0 < \zeta < x$ is attained only when $\zeta = \pi$.  Near there we have

$$
1 - \cos\zeta = 2 - \tfrac{1}{2} (\zeta - \pi)^2 + O\left((\zeta-\pi)^3\right),
$$

so by the Laplace method we obtain the asymptotic

$$
I(x,\lambda) \sim \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[\lambda(2 - \tfrac{1}{2}\zeta^2)\right]\,d\zeta = e^{2\lambda} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}}
$$

as $\lambda \to \infty$.  Replacing $\lambda$ by $1/\epsilon$ we thus obtain an asymptotic for the term in $(2)$ corresponding to the particular solution:

$$
\epsilon^{-1} e^{(\cos x - 1)/\epsilon} \int_0^x e^{(1-\cos \zeta)/\epsilon}\,d\zeta \sim e^{(\cos x + 1)/\epsilon} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\epsilon}}
$$

as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

So, while the homogeneous solution $y(0) e^{(\cos x - 1)/\epsilon}$ decays exponentially (since $\cos x - 1 < 0$ for $2\pi < x < 3\pi$), the remaining part of the solution still contains terms which diverge exponentially as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.