# How can I derive the leading term of asymptotic expansion from WKB approximation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, special-functions

I would like to derive the the asymptotic expansion from the WKB approximation. I thought that is standard and could be found in textbooks, but I did not find any useful materials.

To make the question clear, let us start with an example, say, I have a Bessel's equation,
$$
z^2 y''+z y' +(z^2-\nu^2)y=0,
$$
whose solution is Bessel's functions $J_{\pm\nu}(z)$.
Everyone is familiar with the leading term of asymptotic expansion as $z\to\infty$, that is
$$
J_\nu(z)\sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}\cos\left(z-\frac{\nu \pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right).
$$
***My task is to derive this formula from Bessel's equation by WKB approximation.***

To use the WKB method, I prefer to make a transformation first $y\to y/\sqrt{z}$, which gives
$$
y''+Q(z) y=0,\qquad Q(z)=1+\frac{1/4-\nu^2}{z^2}.
$$
The WKB phase can be calculated analytically
$$
I=\int^z dz \sqrt{Q(z)}
$$
and as $z\to \infty$, one will have
$$
I\sim z+\frac{ \pi}{4}   \sqrt{4 \nu ^2-1}
$$
but the additional constant here is not the phase shift in above cosine function.

Could someone give me a clue of solution, or full derivation, or any relevant references? Thanks in advance.

The similar question for first order differential equation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022899/can-one-apply-a-wkb-method-to-an-inhomogeneous-first-order-differential-equation).

Answer (score 1):

Your equation may be written in the form
$$
\frac{{\mathrm{d}^2 y(z)}}{{\mathrm{d}z^2 }} = ( - f(z) + g(z))y(z)
$$
with
$$
f(z) = 1,\quad g(z) = \frac{{\nu ^2  - 1/4}}{{z^2 }}.
$$
This equation has solutions $y_\pm(z)$ satisfying
$$
y_ \pm  (z) = \exp \left( { \pm \mathrm{i}\int_{}^z {\sqrt {f(t)} \,\mathrm{d}t} } \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{z}} \right)} \right) = C_ \pm  \exp ( \pm \mathrm{i}z)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{z}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $z\to +\infty$, with arbitrary constants $C_\pm$. This can be established from Theorem $2.2$ on p. $196$ of F. W. J. Olver's *Asymptotics and Special Functions*. The Bessel function $\sqrt{z}J_\nu(z)$ will be an appropriate linear combination of these two solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I am more interested in deriving the phase shift $-\nu\pi/2-\pi/4$. In your language, I would like to find the "appropriate linear combination", such that the WKB solution is exactly the well-known leading term of asymptotic expansion.

Comment: I would first identify the Hankel functions in terms of $y_\pm(z)$ using their defining properties http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2.ii Then, using http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.4.E4, you can obtain the asymptotics of the Bessel function.

Comment: I am not agree with your derivation, in particular when you use the asymptotic properties of Hankel functions.If you use these two links, I believe that you can obtain asymptotic formula of Bessel function without WKB method. But thanks anyway.

Comment: That is correct. The problem is that there is only one normalisation point you can use to identify particular solutions, the point at infinity. Thus, you have to have some knowledge on the asymptotics of the Bessel functions at infinity. It seems that WKB is not a useful method to obtain the asymptotics of the Bessel function for large argument. However, it works well when you are dealing with large order or large order and argument (e.g., $J_\nu(\nu z)$).